# WordPress : Why some comments go to spam

Tags: wordpress, jetpack, akismet

I have site and i install `jetpack` and `akismet` in my site, But the problem is some comment go to spam, But its not spam.

How can solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Akismet catches a comment as spam that is not spam, click the "Not Spam" button underneath the comment in the WordPress dashboard. Akismet will learn from this and will be less likely to flag similar comments on your site as spam in the future.

If Akismet continues to catch legitimate comments as spam, contact support@akismet.com so we can take a closer look and determine whether there are fixable issues causing your false positives.

Source: I'm the lead developer on Akismet.